# Input text not showing paste menu in Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, html-framework-7

I'm using [Framework7](http://framework7.io/) for React. And when I open it in Chrome if I press an input text the paste menu is not appearing. If I select a text and I press it the cut/copy menu appears ok.

The menu appears fine:

[image]

The menu is NOT appearing:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This app parameter did the trick:

`touch: {
    disableContextMenu: false
  },`

[Source](http://framework7.io/docs/app.html#app-parameters)